# Javax @Resource annotation does not inject infinispan manager from standalone.xml

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan

I am trying to inject infinispan cache manager object from standalone.xml. I always get null pointer exception for cache manager object.
I am using wildfly 26 and java 17. This is my code for example purposes.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager;


@Path("/testInjection")
public class TestInjection  {

    @Resource(name = "java:jboss/infinispan/container/cacheContainer")
    private EmbeddedCacheManager CACHE_MANAGER;


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/api/versioninfo")
    public void getVersionInfo() throws NamingException {
        if(CACHE_MANAGER != null) {
            System.err.println("positive");

        }else {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            CACHE_MANAGER = (EmbeddedCacheManager) initialContext.lookup("java:jboss/infinispan/container/cacheContainer");
            System.err.println("cache manager null");
        }
    }


}
```

This is the jar I use for resource annotation :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My standalone.xml part for infinispan cache manager:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:13.0">
        .....
        <cache-container name="cacheContainer">
            <local-cache name="cacheExample">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NONE"/>
                <heap-memory size="100"/>
                <expiration lifespan="3600000"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="true"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
```

Any suggestion appreciated at this point I just dont understand why it is not working.
Thanks

Comment: Is the REST resource annotated with anything? Like is it an EJB?

Comment: No it has only path variable in its current version. But I tried with Singleton and Bean annotations in the class but result does not change it still not working. I change the question and wrote whole class, you can check.

Comment: Try adding an EJB annotation like `@Stateless`. CDI doesn't support `@Resource`.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to create a producer like `@Produces @Resource` in a producer.

Comment: Maybe I am missing a point but '@Stateless' and '@Produces' both are not helping.

Comment: But using InitialContext , I can lookup with same JNDI name and retrieve the object. It is just weird at this point.

Comment: Without a reproducer, I'm not too sure. Using an EJB annotation should work though.